# Regular expression in javascript to match only letters or spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following expression to validate a "name":

```
/^([a-z\s?]{4,120})[^\s]$/i
```

But I do not know why accepts special characters: `Alex@` is a valid match.

It should be invalid because I have not specified that contains special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a minimum of 4 characters - you're trying to get it to work with is expecting at least 5 characters because of the non-optional `[^\s]` character at the end. Moreover, `[^\s]` will actually match any character that isn't a space - I'd bet you want to restrict that to being just letters as well?

Try this instead:

```
^[a-z\s?]{3,119}[a-z]$
```